# Handle page refresh when data is dynamically passed to component route?

Tags: angular, typescript, dynamic, angular-material, router

How can I handle a page refresh when the data used in the component only is supplied when it is routed to?

In the code snippet below you can see I am supplying the company object with the route for each row in the table through the router's state object.

company settings component class html

```
<!-- Name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Company</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let company">
            <div fxLayout="column">
                <span>{{ company.EoName }}</span>
                <a routerLink='/company-details' [state]=company><span class="mat-small">Go to details page.</span></a>
            </div>
        </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
```

And then in the component class that gets routed to, I am accessing the state object like this:

company-details component .ts

```
company: ICompany;

constructor(private _router: Router) {
    this.company = this._router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state
}
```

The only way to get to the component template is by clicking the link in the table for that company and that's how the data gets supplied.

Which works fine for my use case but I need to a way to resupply or preserve the same company object if the user decides to refresh the page.

I am looking for a way to either solve this problem or use a different way of providing dynamic data to the component route.

[image]

Comment: Is there anything wrong with good old fashioned query string values?

Comment: Thank you I changed my approach to tackling this problem